# IPv4/IPv6のデュアルスタック環境からIPv6オンリーの環境に移行した時の影響について

Tags: aws, ipv6

AWSが米国連邦政府のシステム要件に合わせて、IPv6のみのVPCサブネットを作成できるようになったことを公式ブログで知りました。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-ipv6-only-subnets-and-ec2-instances/

ただ、この記事ではIPv4/IPv6のデュアルスタック環境からIPv6オンリーの環境に移行した時の影響がよくわかりません。どなたか具体的にこういったケースに影響があるか、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score -1):

IPv4を使っていれば影響を受け、使っていなければ影響を受けないだけでしょう。

使用状況については、例えば[VPCフローログ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)でIPv4通信を全て記録して、用途を確認し順次IPv6に移行することでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ipv4使用時に例えばネットワークセキュリティをNAT Gatewayに担保させるような設計をしてた場合(AWSというよりオンプレですが…)、代替手段としてIPv6ではどうなりますか？

Comment: 元の質問はデュアルスタックが前提でした。しかしNATはIPv4限定の概念でありIPv6には存在しません。NAT Gatewayがセキュリティを担保していたということはすなわちIPv4オンリーととれます。質問の前提が違いますから、新たな質問スレッド（IPv4オンリーからIPv6オンリーへ移行）を立てるべきかと。

Comment: >新たな質問スレッド（IPv4オンリーからIPv6オンリーへ移行）を立てるべきかと。 ありがとうございます。改めて質問なのですが、"IPv4を使っていれば影響を受け、使っていなければ影響を受けないだけでしょう。" ここで想定している影響について教えてください。

Comment: 例えば、ISATAPルーターはこの場合不要になるのでしょうか？(色々な角度から影響が考えられるので包括的にわかる資料などがあれば、ご教授お願いします。)